# How should I calculate the speed of a Lerp?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a Vector2 Lerp statement:

```cs
Vector2.Lerp(spawnPos, target, position);
```

The `position` variable is a number between 0 and 1, and for all intents and purposes, it increments over time. Think of the way I'm tracking `position` as a "playhead," like in music or animation, where a cursor moves from left to right as the playback continues.

I want the object to continue moving *after* it reaches its target, at the same EXACT speed, just infinitely in a direction. I've tried to change the target to the direction multiplied by the distance between the spawn point, but I still can't figure out how to get the correct speed.

Comment: In the real world, speed = distance / time. If you know how far you've travelled, and how long it took you to travel that distance, then you know the speed. If you know the average framerate and how much `position` changes per frame, you could probably estimate time without recording it.

Comment: @Llama thanks so much! this was exactly what i needed & i'll write an answer on it soon :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A slightly easier answer for you: Instead of using `Vector2.Lerp` and calculating everything, just use [Vector2.LerpUnclamped](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.LerpUnclamped.html) and throw in any value of `t` you want!

Comment: ooh, yeah, thats a great solution. ill try that out!

Comment: this was perfect, thanks so much! marked correct due to it being the simplest and most effective answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [Llama](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3181933/llama)'s comment, I was able to calculate the speed of a Lerp.

First, record the start and end time of the interpolation, and whether or not the interpolation has completed (`position >= 1`). Then, if it hasn't finished, lerp as normal. If it HAS finished, note the end time, calculate the speed and direction in which to move, and increment `Transform.position` by that value.

```cs
bool finished = false;

// Since I'm using AudioSettings.dspTime, I need to use double.
// Most forms of telling time in Unity will use float
double startTime;
double endTime;

void Start()
{
    // This is what I am using for my game, 
    // but you can use any way of telling time that Unity/C# provides.
    startTime = AudioSettings.dspTime;
}

void Update()
{
    if(!finished)
    {
        // interpolate
        transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(spawnPos, targetPos, position);
        if(position >= 1)
        {
            // Record our end time
            endTime = AudioSettings.dspTime;
            finished = true
        }
    } else {
        // How long it took to lerp
        double lerpTime = endTime - startTime;
        // How far we lerped
        float distance = Vector2.Distance(spawnPos, targetPos);
        // The speed to further move
        float speed = distance / (float)lerpTime;
        // The direction in which to move
        Vector2 direction = (targetPos - spawnPos).normalized;

        // Continue moving
        transform.position += (Vector3)direction * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `position` come from?

Comment: @derHugo position is based on `AudioSettings.dspTime`, the "playback" position, and a future time

Comment: Well it is neither in your question nor in your answer code ... reason for the question of mine is: Whoever is increasing the `position` over time .. couldn't that one already tell you how long it will take to increase it => can tell you already how fast `position` grows => can already tell you the speed value you are looking for ?